# How to implement email tracking send by email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, tracking

I want to implement email tracking send by email by Rails application.
I want to know how many users open my email.

here I am using Localtunnel

<img src=<%="https://fluffy-lemons-tan-223-236-34-196.loca.lt/user/#{@user.id}/track_email "%> class="profile" />

How to call track_email? means when I open email track_email action has not been calling.

Comment: This should work. Just be aware that a portion of users, me included, disable images in email to prevent exactly this practice.

Comment: Also gmail prefetches all images in an email (or at least used to), before the user opens that email.

Comment: I think sendgrid has built-in tracking of opens, though?